# Deleting child view from first position and adding it to last position

Tags: android, android-view

I have a custom view called `TinderStackLayout`. 
At a certain part of the code I am deleting a child view of it and re-adding it back at the last position possible -

```java
private void handleViewAfterAnimation(View view, boolean shouldSkipView) {
    Log.d("card view - ", "inside handleViewAfterAnimation");
    isCardAnimating = false;
    TinderStackLayout tinderStackLayout = (TinderStackLayout) view.getParent();
    if (tinderStackLayout == null)
      return;
    tinderStackLayout.removeView(view);
    if (shouldSkipView)
      tinderStackLayout.addCard((TinderCardView) view, tinderStackLayout.getChildCount() - 1);

    //this part is for debugging purpose 
    for (int i = 0; i < tinderStackLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
      View childAt = tinderStackLayout.getChildAt(i);
      if (childAt instanceof TinderCardView)
        Log.d("card view - ", "child cards after deletion - " + (((TinderCardView) childAt).usernameTextView.getText()));
    }

  }
```

here is my `addCard()` method -

```java
public void addCard(TinderCardView tinderCardView, int addToPosition) {
    View topCard = getChildAt(0);
    if (topCard != null && topCard.equals(tinderCardView)) {
      return;
    }

    topCardOnStack = tinderCardView;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    addView(tinderCardView, addToPosition, layoutParams);

//    tinderCardView.animate()
//        .x(0)
//        .setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
  }
```

What I don't understand is what I get in the UI - 
I have 3 cards. 
I press the button, one card is being animated away, the second one is being shown. I press the button again, the second one animates away. I press the last one and the button does not work anymore. What I want to achieve is the first card appearing now behind the last one.

Here is what I get when logging the values out -

[image]

seems correct, it was before clicking 3 2 1 and now 2 3 1. The next one should be 1 2 3, but this is what I get for the next one -

[image]

goes back to 3 2 1 instead of 1 2 3. I can't figure out why. ?

**Edit:**

found the reason why this is happening, I am giving a view which should always be the top card on the stack but I am actually not giving the top card because I am always adding a new card. Here is the method -

```java
public void handleButtonPressed(int buttonTag) {
    Log.d("card view - ", "inside handleButtonPressed");
    TinderStackLayout tinderStackLayout = ((TinderStackLayout) this.getParent());
    TinderCardView topCard = (TinderCardView) tinderStackLayout.getChildAt(tinderStackLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    if (isCardAnimating) {
      return;
    }
    switch (buttonTag) {
      case DELETE_BUTTON_PRESSED:
        isCardAnimating = true;
        deleteCard(topCard);
        break;
      case PASS_BUTTON_PRESSED:
        Log.d("card view - ", "inside pass button pressed");
        isCardAnimating = true;
        passCard(topCard);
        Log.d("card view - ", "top card Value before pass - " + topCard.displayNameTextView.getText());
        Log.d("card view - ", "child count - " + tinderStackLayout.getChildCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < tinderStackLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
          View childAt = tinderStackLayout.getChildAt(i);
          if (childAt instanceof TinderCardView)
            Log.d("card view - ", "child cards before deletion - " + (((TinderCardView) childAt).usernameTextView.getText()));
        }
        break;
      case APPROVE_BUTTON_PRESSED:
        showLawyerContactDetailsFragment(topCard);
        break;
    }
  }
```

I am trying to do `TinderCardView topCard = (TinderCardView) tinderStackLayout.getChildAt(tinderStackLayout.getChildCount() - 1)` in order to get the top card in my stack, which would be correct if I delete the cards and not re-add them to my stack but that is not the case when re-adding them. What should be the solution for always getting the top card when I am adding new views all the time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle cards, then you don't need to delete and re-add them. You simply need a data structure, which will do it for you. For your use case you can use Circular Array.

```
private CircularArray cardArray;  //declaration
```

Now when you are adding your views, add it to your card array also.

```
cardArray.addLast(tinderCardView);
addView(tinderCardView); // add to your layout.
```

Then use this code to check.

```
int shuffleCount = 3;
for (int i = 1; i <= shuffleCount; i++)
    shuffleTopCard(i);
```

Finally shuffleTopCard() method.

```
private void shuffleTopCard(int shuffleID) {
    Log.d(TAG, "shuffleTopCard: cards before shuffle");
    for (int i = 0; i < cardCount; i++)
        Log.d(TAG, "shuffleTopCard: " + ((TinderCardView) cardArray.get(i)).getTag());

    TinderCardView cardView = (TinderCardView) cardArray.popLast();

    Log.e(TAG, "shuffleTopCard: top cardID = " + cardView.getTag());
    cardArray.addFirst(cardView);

    Log.d(TAG, "shuffleTopCard: cards after shuffling " + shuffleID + " time");
    for (int i = 0; i < cardArray.size(); i++)
        Log.d(TAG, "shuffleTopCard: " + ((TinderCardView) cardArray.get(i)).getTag());

    Log.e(TAG, "shuffleTopCard: after shuffle top card = " + ((TinderCardView) cardArray.getLast()).getTag());
}
```

Use of CircularArray will free you from head-ache of maintaining card position manually and also separates your CustomViewGroup and card shuffling logic thereby resulting in loosely-coupled code.